# java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I get the following exception when I need to pass in a custom type to my stored proc as an argument

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:114) ~[ojdbc8_g.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:75) ~[ojdbc8_g.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.sql.OracleSQLOutput.writeObject(OracleSQLOutput.java:369) ~[ojdbc8_g.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
```

the last line of the stackstrace here is called from this method

```
public static void writeObject(SQLData object, SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
    stream.writeObject(object);
}
```

where `object` is my custom SQL type.

What might be wrong here?

added the Java object

```
public class Object extends SQLBaseObject {

    public static final String BASE_TYPE_NAME = "object_obj";
    public static final String ARR_TYPE_NAME = "object_arr";

    private Attribute attribute_;
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        super.writeSQL(stream);
        writeObject(attribute_, stream);
```

Comment: Please add your SQL type java rapresentation

Comment: @Renato added. It is a regular Java class that extends SQLBaseObject. "object_obj" and "object_arr" are the SQL types already defined in the database.

Comment: I don't know SQLBaseObject but, my guess is that your jdbc driver doesnt' understand which data structure is associated to your object... then is `getSQLTypeName()` implemented?